# Parse text file into three categories and display as html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text file which has 100+ email ids with various domains of my vendor and clients.

Example:

```
raj@xyz.com,John@gyx.com
```

I want to place a button which extracts and displays email id with xyz.com and another one which retuns gyx.com likewise. Without PHP I don't have  a local server installed.

I have no idea where to start.

This is the code I currently use to read the text file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Read File (via User Input selection)</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var reader; 
    function checkFileAPI() {
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
            reader = new FileReader();
            return true; 
        } else {
            alert('The File APIs are not fully supported by your browser. Fallback required.');
            return false;
        }
    }

    function readText(filePath) {
        var output = ""; //placeholder for text output
        if(filePath.files && filePath.files[0]) {           
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                output = e.target.result;
                displayContents(output);
            };//end onload()
            reader.readAsText(filePath.files[0]);
        }//end if html5 filelist support
        else if(ActiveXObject && filePath) { //fallback to IE 6-8 support via ActiveX
            try {
                reader = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                var file = reader.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1); //ActiveX File Object
                output = file.ReadAll(); //text contents of file
                file.Close(); //close file "input stream"
                displayContents(output);
            } catch (e) {
                if (e.number == -2146827859) {
                    alert('Unable to access local files due to browser security settings. ' + 
                     'To overcome this, go to Tools->Internet Options->Security->Custom Level. ' + 
                     'Find the setting for "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe" and change it to "Enable" or "Prompt"'); 
                }
            }       
        }
        else { //this is where you could fallback to Java Applet, Flash or similar
            return false;
        }       
        return true;
    }   

    /**
     * display content using a basic HTML replacement
     */
    function displayContents(txt) {
        var el = document.getElementById('main'); 
        el.innerHTML = txt; //display output in DOM
    }   
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkFileAPI();">
    <div id="container">    
        <input type="file" onchange='readText(this)' />
        <br/>
        <hr/>   
        <h3>Contents of the Text file:</h3>
        <div id="main">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Likely the reason you don't know where to start is that, as described, it's totally unclear what you're wanting to do.

Comment: are you trying to use drag and drop?

Comment: so.... any answers solve this older question of yours? if so, mark one as solved. You too gain good reputation at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the high level approach I would take:

Once the document has loaded up, using jQuery I would grab all of the data output.

```
var output = $('#main').val()
```

Then, I would write some logic to parse out the data from the output variable into two different sets (@xyz list and @gyx list). Also, I would format the output too so that it's ready to be called on. Now you have the two data sets that you need, and can call on them when you push your button.

Create an event with jQuery based on the button click state. Depending on the state, the method would select the appropriate list, and then display the output.

So rather than extracting the appropriate data on every button press, you can front load all of it in the initial page load. Since the data won't be changing until you refresh the page again, you should just use the button to switch between which list gets displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to search your email address list, displaying ids that match a domain or a domains matching an id.  First I would take the advice given above and offload your file content into a variable.

This is easy given a comma separated list of email addresses, and [here's a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3O7aASA6T5TzgTEO3l4U?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality you want (sans the file loading code etc.).

Here's a function to find matches in the address lists based on your criteria.

```
/** 
@emails is a comma separated list of email addresses.
@term is the search term e.g. email id or domain.
@compareById if truthy the function returns email domains with 
   email id == @text otherwise the function returns email id's 
   with email domain == @text.
*/
function getEmailMatches(emails, term, compareById) {
    let matches = [],
      compareIndex = compareById ? 0 : 1,
      valueIndex = compareById ? 1 : 0;

    emails.split(",").forEach(function (email) {
        let terms = email.split("@");
        if (terms[compareIndex] == term)
            matches.push(terms[valueIndex]);
    });

    return matches;
}
```